# Need to display the highest priced item in Magento Grouped Product.

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have read through the tier pricing but that is not what I am looking for. Currently Magento displays the lowest priced item in a group but our products in one group can range from $3,000 to $5.00. I would like to switch it so that the highest priced item in the group displays as opposed to the lowest price. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$groupedPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_grouped_price'); 
echo $groupedPrice->getMaxPrice($_product->getId());
```

This is if you use grouped products on your site.

Comment: Would this be placed in the price.php file for grouped products?

Comment: in catalog/product/price.phtml towards the bottom near this line:
<?php else: /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>

Comment: Here is part of what I did. The file is just too big to add as a comment but it should be the meat of what you need to accomplish your goal

 <?php $groupedPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_grouped_price'); ?>
    <?php if($groupedPrice->getMinPrice($_product->getId()) == $groupedPrice->getMaxPrice($_product->getId())): ?>
   <?php $_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $groupedPrice->getMinPrice($_product->getId())); ?>
      <?php $_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $groupedPrice->getMinPrice($_product->getId()), true); ?>

Have a look at one of my grouped products

Comment: http://www.lightsnholsters.com/leupold-8-5-25x50-mark-4-er-t-m5-front-focal-tactical-rifle-scope/

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to get it how yours looks but was able to get it so that the pricing does not show up until you have clicked on the grouped product which works just as well in our situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance ( true )->getSelectionsCollection ( $product->getTypeInstance ( true )->getOptionsIds ( $product ), $product );
$grouped_items = array ();
foreach ( $selectionCollection as $option ) {
    $grouped_items [] = $item;
}
foreach ( $grouped_items as $item) {
        $arrayPrice [] = $item->getPrice;
}
maxPrice = max($arrayPrice);
```